# Why does this solution not double count?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

Question:

> A pack of cards consists of $52$ different cards. A malicious dealer
> changes one of the cards for a second copy of another card in the pack
> and he then deals the cards to four players, giving thirteen to each.
> What is the probability that one player has the two identical cards?

Proposed solution I found online that leads to an answer I know to be correct:

> Consider any player and the probability that he gets the two duplicate
> cards.
>
> There are: $52\choose13$ possible hands he could get.
>
> But he gets the two duplicate cards (1 way) and 11 more cards: $50\choose11$
> ways.
>
> His probability is:
> $\frac{50\choose11}{52\choose13}=\frac{1}{17}$
>
> Since this could happen to any of the four players, the probability is $\frac{4}{17}$

I do not understand why $52\choose13$ is the number of possible hands. A quick sanity check would be that introducing duplicates must change(decrease?) the number of distinguishable hands as opposed to an ordinary deck. This can be seen by considering the number of hands if all cards are duplicates.

I think the number of possible hands is ${51\choose13} + 1*1*{50\choose11}$, the number of hands without using the second copy + the number of hands using the first copy and the second copy, since the number of hands using the first copy but not the second are indistinguishable from the hands using the second copy but not the first.

Though, I struggle to believe using such large numbers that their answer just turned out to be correct. Could somebody please explain where I am misunderstanding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main error is in not clearly differentiating what are the observable outcomes of the card dealing to one player vs. what the underlying structure of cards dealt is.

The underlying structure is important because it makes sure that we understand what events have equal probability.

A historical example is that two mathematicians debated what happens if you throw two equal (not distinguishable) fair 6 sided dice. Would sum 12 come up less often or more often or as often as sum 11?

Praxis shows sum 11 comes up roughly twice as often as sum 12 in long experiments. But one mathematicion argued that there is only one way each to get sums 11 and 12: 6+5 and 6+6, resp., so it **should** be the same probability.

The question becomes clearer if we make the dice distinguishable, say one is red in background, the other green. Then we see that there is still only one one way to get sum 12: red 6 + green 6. But now there are two ways to get sum 11: red 6 + green 5 and red 5 + green 6.

They key point is that the outcome of the experiment doesn't depend on the color or other characteristics of the dice, as long as they are both fair. But when considering them as indistinguishable, one is making an error in assuming that "a 5 and a 6" comes up as often as "a 6 and a 6".

In your case, you are right that the number of possible observable hands a player can get decreases. But what's even more important, just as in the above dice example, is that the probability for different observable hands is no longer the same!

A hand not containing the "double" card is as likely as before. But a hand containing the "double" card just once is now double likely as before, because there are two instances of that card that can create that hand.

So while counting observable hands might be an interesting task, it is no real help when dealing with probabilities, as (unlike before) the **observable hands are not equally likely**.

The usually best course of action for probability calculations is to consider everything distinguishable and make sure to define the events in such a way as to coincide with what can be observerd, as the solution cited did.

It considered the 2 "double" cards different, so came up with again $52 \choose 13$ possible hands a player can get. Some of them will not be distinguishable to the player, but all those $52 \choose 13$ hands are equally likely.

Your calculation of different observable hands is correct, but, as I explained above, they are not equally likely to occur, so a simple "good hands divided by all hands" formula is **not** coming up with he correct probability.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG let's say we are swapping out $\mathrm{A}\spadesuit$, and replace it with $\color{red}{\mathrm{K}\heartsuit}$.

Instead of swapping the card out followed by dealing the cards to the four players, let's consider dealing the cards out to the four players followed by swapping the card out. These two make no difference, as ultimately the same person will get the same pair of cards, if any.

From the second perspective, this then reduces to the question of the probability of a player getting both $\mathrm{A}\spadesuit$ and $\color{red}{\mathrm{K}\heartsuit}$. The working you showed addresses precisely this.

Comment: This makes sense. Do you think for piece of mind you could give me an abstract example of a deck that I overcounted with my (incorrect) reasoning or some insight into why it derails?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consider $50$ cards separately and $2$ duplicate cards separately, here is the number of combinations to choose $13$ cards from them -

${50 \choose 11} {2 \choose 2} + {50 \choose 12} \times {2 \choose 1} + {50 \choose 13} {2 \choose 0} = 635013559600$. This is same as $52 \choose 13$.

Now the question is why ${50 \choose 12} \times {2 \choose 1}$ and why not ${50 \choose 12} \times 1$. This is simply because it is a question on probability and not combinatorics. All events are not equally probable. Say we toss two identical coins - there are only $3$ possible combinations $\, (2H, 2T, 1H \, 1T)$. But the probability of getting $(1H 1T)$ is $\frac{1}{2}$, $2H$ is $\frac{1}{4}$ and $2T$ is $\frac{1}{4}$.

By the way, another way to look at this probability problem is - say one of the duplicate cards has gone to one of the persons. Now what is the probability that the next card will also go to the same person $= \frac{12}{51} = \frac{4}{17}$.